# How to read nested json file with several roots in extjs

Tags: json, extjs4

How to read the following json file and display in extjs grid columns?

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Ed",
            "orders": [
                {
                    "id": 50,
                    "total": 100,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Could someone explain how to read the nested data in the json? I have tried a lot of options like renderer functions, using the '.' property, etc.

Edit: I would like to read the data within "orders", which are "id" and "total".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read in an array nested in an object nested in an array.

So your root would have to be users[0].orders

Is that really what you are trying to do?

Working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/el_chief/s6Ynp/1/

Why is your code nested like this?

Comment: This was great!! Thanks a lot. This displays perfectly in the grid panel. However, I am trying to display this in a radar chart. Now, charts in extjs receive data and need to display immediately. So I need to use 'listeners' and the 'load: function(store)'. how can i read such a data and display in the chart?

Comment: Also, now I want to display the 'id' and 'name' of 'users'.

Comment: I hope I got the upvoting correctly :) Can you help me with the rendering of the nested jason in the radar chart? Any docs or links or suggestions will be of great help..... The json file can be simplified to the following now {
    "result": {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Ed",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 2700,
                    "total": 100,
                }
            ]
        }
} Although I would like to read in all the fields.....